# Get the name of the currently executing method

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

`$0` is the variable for the top level Ruby program, but is there one for the current method?

Comment: One use is checking `super` can be called within a SimpleDelegator object: `def description; __getobj__.respond_to?(__method__) ? super : 'No description'; end`

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Even better than my first answer you can use `__method__`:

```rb
class Foo
  def test_method
    __method__
  end
end
```

This returns a symbol – for example, `:test_method`. To return the method name as a string, call `__method__.to_s` instead.

**Note:** This requires Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: the ':' is just the symbol symbol. :)
just do `__method__.to_s` and it'll be the method name, nothing else

Comment: What if I am in rake task?

Answer (score 37):

Depending on what you actually want, you can use either `__method__` or `__callee__`, which return the currently executing method's name as a symbol.

On ruby 1.9, both of them behave identically (as far as the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) and my testing are concerned).

On ruby 2.1 & 2.2 `__callee__` behaves differently if you call an alias of the defined method. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) for the two are different:

- `__method__`: "the name at the definition of the current method" (i.e. the name as it was defined)
- `__callee__`: "the called name of the current method" (i.e. the name as it was called (invoked))

Test script:

```
require 'pp'
puts RUBY_VERSION
class Foo
  def orig
    {callee: __callee__, method: __method__}
  end
  alias_method :myalias, :orig
end
pp( {call_orig: Foo.new.orig, call_alias: Foo.new.myalias} )
```

1.9.3 Output:

```
1.9.3
{:call_orig=>{:callee=>:orig, :method=>:orig},
 :call_alias=>{:callee=>:orig, :method=>:orig}}
```

2.1.2 Output (`__callee__` returns the aliased name, but `__method__` returns the name at the point the method was defined):

```
2.1.2
{:call_orig=>{:callee=>:orig, :method=>:orig},
 :call_alias=>{:callee=>:myalias, :method=>:orig}}
```

Answer (score 28):

From http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2785:

```
module Kernel
private
    def this_method_name
      caller[0] =~ /`([^']*)'/ and $1
    end
end

class Foo
  def test_method
    this_method_name
  end
end

puts Foo.new.test_method    # => test_method
```

Comment: This was very helpful to me for finding the name of the *calling* (as opposed to the current) method.

Comment: Does `__callee__` not do this?

Comment: Great solution Mark

The best solution at now. Great job

Answer (score 13):

For Ruby 1.9+ I'd recommend using `__callee__`

Comment: `__callee__` behaves differently prior to 1.9, so it's best to stick with `__method__` since it has consistent behavior. `__callee__` behaves the same as `__method__` after 1.9.

Comment: @LeighMcCulloch can you explain the difference with an example (possibly in a new answer)?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视 `def m1() puts("here is #{__method__} method. My caller is #{__callee__}.") end; def m2() puts("here is #{__method__} method. Let's call m1"); m1 end; m2` Don't you see anything strange ?

Comment: @LeighMcCulloch actually now `__callee__` and `__method__` has different behaviour. See http://pastie.org/10380985 (ruby 2.1.5)

Comment: pastie.org is down. Forever or just now?

Comment: In Ruby 2.6, I have an aliased method: `__method__` returned me the name of the real method (the one filled with code), `__callee__` returned the alias used.

Answer (score -3):

I got the same issue to retrieve method name in view file. I got the solution  by

```
params[:action] # it will return method's name
```

if you want to get controller's name then

```
params[:controller] # it will return you controller's name
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question to be about rails controller actions & http methods... this answer should probably be deleted.

Comment: Useful for getting the name of the currently executing (controller) method from the view.