# How to Dynamically Determine a Method Name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, is there a way to determine the name of a method, akin to how the "class" method returns an object's type?

For example:

```
def example_method
  puts method_name
end

#=> "example_method"
```

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method, from [**here**](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/75258):

```
module Kernel
 private
  def current_method_name
    caller[0] =~ /`([^']*)'/ and $1
  end
end


class Foo
 def test_method
   current_method_name   # "test_method"
 end
end
```

This works in older versions of Ruby (< 1.9). For newer versions, see the other StackOverflow answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby)** highlighted by Ben.