# Does Ruby 1.8 have an equivalent to 1.9's __callee__?

Tags: ruby, introspection

I need to grab the name of the lexically enclosing method in Ruby 1.8; e.g.

```
def foo
  this_method = __callee__  # => 'foo'
end
```

The above code is valid in Ruby 1.9, but fails in 1.8, since __callee__ was introduced in 1.9.

Any suggestions for doing this in 1.8? *Kernel#caller* looked promising, but seems to give me the call stack starting with the caller of the method, not the method itself.

I guess I could throw an exception, catch it, and grab the first element in the *Exception#backtrace* array, but my gut tells me that will be slow.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ruby 1.8.7 there is the `__method__`, not sure about 1.8.6.

Anyway, You can monkey patch the `Kernel` module:

```
module Kernel
  # Defined in ruby 1.9
  unless defined?(__callee__)
    def __callee__
      caller[0] =~ /`([^']*)'/ and $1
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked whether the "backports" gem has it?

Comment: The "backports" gem, has `__callee__`.  I found it in the source for backports 1.18.2, complete with a test.

Comment: Is `__callee__` any different from `__method__`?

Comment: @Josh Glover, Not if you can believe its definition in backports: `  alias_method :__callee__, :__method__  unless (__callee__ || true rescue false)`.  Formatting has taken away some double-underscores, but you get the idea.