# self.name returns error? Ruby1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I would like to be able to identify what the name of the method is from the method which is currently being called.  I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class SomeClass
  def initialize
    puts self.name
  end
end
p = SomeClass.new
```

but receive the following error:

```
./test.rb:4:in `initialize': undefined method `name' <SomeClass:0x007fe4d107ba30 (NoMethodError)
  from ./test.rb:7:in `new'
  from ./test.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

How do I call the method I am calling from?

Comment: Just as a heads up, there's the Class#name method, which is unrelated to what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the name of the currently executing method in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize
    puts __callee__
  end
end
p = SomeClass.new #=> initialize
```

`__method__` and `__callee__` are synonyms

Comment: Here are the docs for [`__callee__`/`__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) for reference. (Edit: SO messes up the URL, so here it is plain: `http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__`

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby methods are not regular objects that programmer can operate on them like they can do on Strings and Arrays. Thus, although `Method` class has `name()` method, when you call `name()` method it is searched in `SomeClass` and its ancestors which are `[Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

You can see this by checking `self` in any method definition in `SomeClass`. It will return `SomeClass` as self.

Therefore, you get `undefined method` exception. You can use `__method__` to get current method name.

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize
    puts __method__
  end
end
```

`__method__` returns symbol. You can use `to_s` method to get the string representation of method.

Comment: `Method.name` is a method? why does calling self.name from a method not return the name of the method?

Comment: @KurtRudolph Because `self` isn't the method, it's the instance of the class.