# How to retrieve the current method name so to output it to the logger file?

Tags: ruby, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and, in order to display warning messages for development purposes, I am using `logger.warn` in my code. I would like to retrieve the *method name* in which that `logger.warn` runs so to output that method name to the log file.

```
class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_name
    # Note: This code doesn't work. It is just a sample.
    logger.warn "I would like to retrieve and display the #{self.class.to_s}##{method_name}"
  end
end
```

In the log file I would like to see:

> I would like to retrieve and display the ClassName#method_name

Is it possible? If so, how can I make that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the name of the currently executing method in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
class ClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_name
    logger.warn("I would like to retrieve and display the #{self.class}##{__method__}")
  end
end
```

this should do the job.

Comment: The `.to_s` calls are superfluous.  The interpolation will automatically call `to_s`.