# How to know which method I am currently in

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Inside one method I am writing, how can my code know which method it is currently in? I need this because I want to get the method name and parse it to get a part of it, such as "add_order", then I can use the second part "order" to work on.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467625/how-to-retrieve-the-current-method-name-so-to-output-it-to-the-logger-file

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby

Comment: @halfelf that one is for getting the caller method name and not the one you are currently in

Comment: @RedSerpent try `caller(0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `__method__` to get the name of the method you are currently in

Comment: You are right. I just found it! http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_mname
  caller[0]=~/`(.*?)'/  # quote is a backtick
  $1
end

def name_of_my_method
  puts get_mname
end

name_of_my_method

# => name_of_my_method
```