# If previous method ==?

Tags: ruby

I would like to check when running a method, if it was called from a different method.

EX:

```
def method1(foo)
  if # foo previous method == method2
    #code
  elsif # foo previous method == method 3
    #code
  end
end

def method2
  method1(foo)
end
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `caller` from `Kernel` as described in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller, although you'll need to extract the method name from the string that `caller[0]` returns.

Update: The little regex to extract the method name is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100339/1008891.

Comment: A small clarification for readers who do not wish to check the docs: `caller` returns an array of strings that identifies the current execution stack.  The first element of the array gives you calling method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good clarification - my answer was pretty cryptic. I updated it slightly.