# How can ruby logger set the progname automatically based on the method

Tags: ruby, logging

I have set up my logger using a module with the following (simplified) version:

```
module Logging
  class << self
    def logger
    end
    def logger=(logger)
      @logger = logger
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to do something like the following (it didn't work):

[Get the name of the currently executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method)

```
def test_method 
  return __callee__
end
```

This way without the above, add `logger.progname = self.test_method`

So it should look like this:

```
module Logging
  class << self
    def logger
      return @logger if @logger
      @logger.progname = self.test_method
    end
    def logger=(logger)
      @logger = logger
    end
  end
end
```

The end goal should be such that, with method "MyMethod":

```
def my_method
  logger.debug "hi"
end
```

I get `=> "my_method: "hi"`

Comment: play around with [`caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) it should help you get what you want

Comment: cool, looks like the right step...will let you know.