# How to get integer value while adding new method to Integer class

Tags: ruby

I want to add new method to Integer class, but I have no idea how to access integer value in this method:

```
class Integer
  def foo
    'foo' * value
  end
end
```

It should work like:

```
3.foo
=> 'foofoofoo'
```

Comment: This is not particular to integers, by the way. `self` *always* references the receiver, not just in integers.

Comment: @zerozero7 I have updated my answer. It may be of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `self`:

```
class Integer
  def foo
    'foo' * self
  end
end
#It should work like:

p 3.foo
#=> 'foofoofoo'
```

You can also use [`Kernel#__method__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199560/5101493) for a more general approach:

```
class Integer
  def foo
    __method__.to_s * self
  end
end

p 3.foo
#=> 'foofoofoo'
```