# Get the name of the currently if condition declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-block

I was wondering if it was possible to pass as parameter the if condition statement as string or symbol. Because method name or if statement name could change and if I need it to refacto things it's better to work with a variable, 
here an example inside a simple update method.

`#within any controller`

```rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  include RedirectAfterFooUpdate
  # other methods
  def update
    @foo.update(place_params)
    if  @foo.save
      action_after_update_foo(some_parameters)
    else
      # error redirection...
    end
  end 
end
```

`#within a module need to set correct action after update foo`

```rb
module RedirectAfterFooUpdate

  def action_after_update_foo(some_parameters)

    if  condiction_1
      do_something(condiction_1.to_s.to_sym) #do_something(:condiction_1)

    elsif condiction_2
      do_something_else(condiction_2.to_s.to_sym) #do_something_else(:condiction_2)


    elsif condiction_3
      do_something_else_again(condiction_3.to_s.to_sym) #do_something_else_again(:condiction_3)

    else 
      #casual code

    end
  end
end
```

the code above is clearly simplified and i actually have many other paramaters, but the thing is really focus on the "if statement" => condiction_1 or condiction_2 or condiction_3. How could we get the name of it .
The question [Get the name of the currently executing method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199560/7800866) is not really helpful in that case because I do not need the root method name `action_after_update_foo`.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. In `action_after_update_foo(some_parameters)` you want to pass something that in the `action_after_update_foo` method is just passed as a symbol to the `do_something` method. Why don't you just pass a symbol directly to the  `do_something` method in the first place. Why the intermediate `action_after_update_foo` method?

Comment: I understand your proposition, thanks a lot. If I pass a symbol directly to the "do_something", like for instance ```:the_foo_update_need_to_destroy_all_its_dates```. You are absolutely right I can do this and to tell the true this how my method run. But I would find a way to make it dynamic. If the condition is for instance ```if only_refund_changed``` i would like to pass that name as parameter to the  do_something method => do_something(only_refund_changed)

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions are just method invocations, you could use the following approach that uses Ruby's `send` method to evaluate each condition:

```
module RedirectAfterFooUpdate
  def action_after_update_foo(some_parameters)
    # Declare the conditions that represents method invocations
    conditions = [
      :only_refund_changed,
      :another_condition_x,
      :another_condition_y
    ]
    conditition_executed = false

    conditions.each do |condition|
      # Executes each if / elsif block
      if !conditition_executed && send(condition)
        # Invoke do_something with the condition as a symbol
        do_something(condition)

        conditition_executed = true
      end
    end

    # Executes the else block
    if !conditition_executed
      #casual code
    end
  end
end
```